# every time i open my parrot OS terminal i get bash: ‘export: command not found

Tags: linux, path, bashrc, gnome-terminal, parrot-os

I prefer Linux. I accidentally executed a misspelled command in terminal.

```
sudo echo 'export PATH=/home/grump/miniconda3/bin:$PATH' >> /.bashrc
```

What can I do now that it is constantly executing and I want to get rid of it?

Comment: Remove the line from `.bashrc`

Comment: I have to assume that isn't the command you ran. `/.bashrc` is not going to happen and even if it did happen, your profile wouldn't load it.  If you look at the path above, `/` is at the ROOT of the file system where your user has no rights to party.  In addition, bash will not attempt to load it's profile from here.

Comment: how can i remove it? am just a beginner as i told you. if you can give me an instruction it would be helpful. @Toto

Comment: sorry for my mistake in the question, i run the command with root privilege. @SeñorCMasMas

Comment: Just remove it.  `sudo rm /.bashrc`.  If you need to use sudo, think hard.  If it involves your profile or anything like that, sudo is not needed.